# Why do I keep getting stack overflow errors? Why does my function return at the first value? when start does != the last value

Tags: java

This is the question:
Write a recursive method that removes all consecutively occurring letters from a string of fixed size. E.g. “AAAbbCCCC” becomes “AbC”

My Code:

```
public static String NoRepeats(String n, int start) {
    String x = "";
    if(start == n.length()-1) {
        return x;
    }
    if(n.charAt(start) == n.charAt(start+1)) {
        return NoRepeats(n, start+1);
    }
    else {
        x += n.charAt(start);
        return NoRepeats(n,start+=1);
    }       
}
```

Comment: this will only return an empty string

Comment: Unrelated:read about Java naming conventions, method names go camelCase always.

Comment: Garr is correct: you are changing X in your else case, but that string is never returned. And rename "start", that is more like an index. Finally: when you don't know what your code is doing, then either use a debugger or alternatively add simple print statements so you can observe what your code is doing. Yout code runs right in front of you. Don't rely on others to figure what it is doing.

Comment: at the bottom, "start+=1" can be "start + 1" because 'start' is never used after that.  And that means that the return line is the same for both the 'if' and 'else' cases. But the "x += n.charAt(start)" doesn't do anything.  That means that the 'if' and 'else' clauses do the exact same thing.  That can't be what is desired.

Answer (score 4):

ok, so I wasn't sure why it would only return an empty string, So I fiddled around with the syntax.
FYI String n = "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD"
In my recursive steps I couldn't use 'start ++ or start +1", it only worked when it was 'start +=1'. This will correct it.
This is my new code:

```
public static String NoRepeats(String n, int start) {
        String x = "";
        if(start == (n.length()-1)) {
            x += n.charAt(start);
            return x;
        }
        if(n.charAt(start) == n.charAt(start+1)) {
            return NoRepeats(n, start+=1);
        }
        else {
            x += n.charAt(start);
            return x +NoRepeats(n,start+=1);
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Great job!  This was, in effect, what I came up with.  I just eliminated the variable 'x', but that meant I had to do '"" + charAt(start)' in the first 'if'.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering why did the above returned empty string so I went and modify your codes to see how it's done.

```
String a = "";
String b = "";

    try {
        a = Tesst1.NoRepeats("AAAbbCCCC", 0, b);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(a);
}

public static String NoRepeats(String n, int start, String b) {
    if(start == n.length()-1) {
        return b += n.charAt(start - 1);
    }
    if(n.charAt(start) == n.charAt(start+1)) {
        return NoRepeats(n, start+1, b);
    }
    else {
        b += n.charAt(start);

        return NoRepeats(n,start+1, b);
    }       
}
```

This should now yield AbC.

Answer (score -1):

In your code x is local to function. So, with every call you lose the value of x. Also, there was little mistake in first statement.

In classic way, you could use the result of function:

```
public static String noRepeats(String n, int start) {
    return (start == n.length() - 1) ? "" + n.charAt(start) :
        (n.charAt(start) == n.charAt(start + 1)) ? noRepeats(n, start + 1) :
                n.charAt(start) + noRepeats(n, start + 1);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(noRepeats("AAAbbCCCC", 0));
}
```

Or need some buffer to accumulate new characters:

```
public static String noRepeats(String n) {
    return noRepeats(n, new StringBuilder(), 0);
}

public static String noRepeats(String n, StringBuilder result, int start) {
    if(start == n.length() - 1) {
        return result.append(n.charAt(start)).toString();
    }
    if(n.charAt(start) == n.charAt(start + 1)) {
        return noRepeats(n, result, start + 1);
    }
    else {
        result.append(n.charAt(start));
        return noRepeats(n, result, start + 1);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(noRepeats("AAAbbCCCC"));
}
```

Comment: If you have to use a StringBuilder, you're obviating the whole purpose of recursion.  The point of recursion is to give you a series of contexts that provide different parts of the answer without an accumulation buffer.  If you introduce an accumulation buffer, there's no reason to use recursion at all.  Recursion gives you a "a + b + c" where each term is a stack frame level.  See @Pallof's answer.  No buffer there.